# in ERD of a system in which teachers evaluating other teachers of their departments how can i connect Teacher, evaluation_result entiy,

Tags: erd

A teacher could be an evaluator and also be an evaluatee. How can I achieve this?

[image: ERD diagramm]

Answer (score 0):

You would just add another foreign key to Eval_Result to link to the Evaluatee

So you would have:

### Teacher

- T_ID - primary key
- Teacher info - other fields

### Eval_Result

- Eval_ID - primary key
- Evaluator_ID - teacher that did the evaluation - foreign key to Teacher
- Evaluatee_ID - teacher being evaluated - foreign key to Teacher
- Results - other fields

Answer (score 0):

`Teacher` as evaluator can evaluate multiple Teachers (evaluatees). This is a one-to-many self-referencing relationship.

> Evaluator -|--< Evaluatee

**Teacher:**

```
id [Primary Key]
name
evaluator [Foreign Key referencing Teacher's id]
evaluation result id [Foreign Key referencing Evaluation Result's id]
```

**Evaluation Result:**

```
id [Primary Key]
result details
```

A Teacher (evaluatee) can have one evaluation result.

> Teacher (evaluatee) -|--|- Evaluation Result